# How much balance required for UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds, saudi-citizens

I am planning to travel to Glasgow for 15 days (2 adults and 2 childern). How much funds are sufficient in bank account if I am applying from Saudi Arabia?
I will be staying there at sister place.

Also do I have to maintain a certain balance for 3 months or simple bank statement of salary account along letter from employer?

Comment: A letter from employer showing the salary is usually enough if the salary is big enough, but just in case bring your bank statement along. Last time I applied for a UK visa (in saudi) I didn't bring a statement, but I was alone maybe things are different when you are sponsoring others.

Answer (score 3):

According [Official List of documents for UK Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) there is no fixed amount you must have to apply the visa. But it is a general rule that visa applicants must have enough money to support and accommodate themselves without working or help from public funds, or they and any dependants will be supported and accommodated by relatives or friends:

> Section 2: other documents you **may** want to provide – all visitors
> **Financial documents** showing that you have **sufficient funds** available.
> These must **clearly show that you have access to the funds**, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company
>   contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to
>   you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they
>   have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and
>   any dependant family should be provided

So you should ask in UK Embassy for this, and they'll decide by themselves, as this is very dependent of many factors. I think that about **200 GBP per day** will be OK, but can't say for sure.

Comment: +1, For GBP 200, you assume central London, right?

Comment: That partly answered my question. Do i need to show a maintained balance on month on month basis? or deposit some good amount in my salary account and get the statement. Will that suffice the purpose?

Comment: @nauman That totally depends on your local Embassy. I know both types of requests here in Saint-Petersburg, but it seems that they doesn't have any strict rules available from the outside.

Comment: @Gayot Yep, I've considered big city efforts for my family :)

Comment: @VMAtm, I know the ECO and ECM in Saint Petersburg.  Very decent people and they take a pragmatic/flexible approach.  When they refuse, you can bet the application was seriously in default.

Comment: @GayotFow No< there were no refusals - but from one my friend they requested some bank account statement with salary income, and from another - only the deposit for a vacation. I meant only that the situation is always different, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying for a TOURIST visit visa, then you will need to show a healthy bank balance. You mentioned that your company will be sponsor your trip. That would mean that it is a business visit visa. You will require a letter from your company confirming that all expenses will be covered by them. Show them the supporting salary certificates and they might be able to grant you the visa. Do you have a corporate credit card? Take those statements too as they might help

Comment: There's actually no such thing as a UK business visit visa.  But notwithstanding good intentions on your answer, why do you think corporate credit card statements would help?  Can you differentiate your answer from that given by VMAtm? As it stands, it's doubtful you have added something useful to an existing answer (VMAtm's) which already provides unassailable citations and is of reasonably high quality.

Comment: no no listed i was not add any thing useful its my search and corporate credit card will definitely works see its benefits on
http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/corporate-credit-card-1267.php

Comment: If corporate credit card statements are useful, would you please explain why and in what form?  I have a corporate credit card and might find that information helpful.  Comments are not the place for substantive information.  Edit your answer.

Comment: go to the link: http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/corporate-credit-card-1267.php

Comment: Dude, you don't get it.  The *ANSWER* needs to contain something supporting your view about corporate credit card statements.  The UKVI guidance says they are not helpful. You say they are.  Please don't sign post me to a credit card site.

Comment: in August 2014 my uncle visited to UK and their corporate credit card helps him to get visa

Comment: he said there are agents who can listed our credit card with our visa details and then they are responsible and after 15 days they get their visa

Comment: Well, if your uncle says so, why don't you put that in your answer?

Comment: because i was remember at that time when you ask me for that

Comment: Look around near your answer and you will find an option called "edit"...  That's how you update your answer

Comment: Its not a business trip. I am going on personal trip .Do i need to show a maintained balance on month on month basis? or deposit some good amount in my salary account and get the statement. Will that suffice the purpose?